# Draw circle using square pattern

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics2d

[image]

Hi everybody
I just wonder how we can use these pattern to draw a circle.
My question is a little vague, i'm using unity now, but just asking on general 
Thank :D

Comment: What do you mean "use these(sic) pattern to draw a circle"?

Comment: Do you mean using line stipple or maybe textures?

Comment: I download and look into some 2d-game resource, and realized that they use one of these rectangle pattern to draw circle sprite. 

Here is a example
http://i.upanh.com/vtrkwn

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate circle with textured polygons (quads or triangles). If polygon count is high enough, you probably wouldn't see their (flat) edges, so it will look almost a circle.

Other way is to draw quad and just calculate circle within it, with fragment shader. This method will require descent enough hardware, of course.